# Android LinearLayout over another in ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

How to make a Linearlayout to cover over on top of another Linearlayout in ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "cover". There is only one root element. Nothing "covers" anything (except floating views...) since all other elements are "children"

Comment: add them to a relative layout inside `ConstraintLayout` that is if you still want to use `ConstraintLayout` but you are free to not use it!

Comment: To cover means to be over and on top of something else, so what's underneath is not seen, but only what's on top is seen. ConstraintLayout is the new Android Studio standard. LinearLayout and ConstraintLayout are both one words(no space within) according to Android Studio.

Comment: @AtefHares Please, the whole point of ConstraintLayout is to bury RelativeLayout. It does the same thing but faster, if used as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio 2.3.1 built on 2017 April 1
will automatically add " android:elevation="1dp" ",
and that will prevent the 2nd layer(LinearLayout in my case) to show up on the very top.
And I am on the default ConstraintLayout working fine :)